# Easy to use database software to maintain music inventory

Tags: database, inventory

A friend of mine - a typical babyboomer - has a very extensive music inventory, especially a lot of *compilation albums*. He used to maintain a database software program called Reflex. Every time he bought a new compilation album he entered all artists and titles of the songs on that album.

The result is a database with one entry per song that he owned. The entry has three headers: title, artist and location. He mostly buys new compilation albums because they contain one or multiple songs that he likes. The database is used to check whether he already has an album that contains that song. He also uses it to check which album he needs to retrieve whenever he wants to listen to a specific song that he knows he owns.

So, I managed to run a DOS emulation on my server to run his old software. With this software, I succeeded in extracting a CSV file that contains all three values for every entry (title, artist, location/album). What I need now is modern software. I need to be able to inject the current database (CSV), and subsequently he can keep track of his inventory (search, update, delete). If possible, he would like the possibility of checking the database from his iPhone.

If you are familiar with software that has these functionalities, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is are interested in DIY?  It would be super easy to import those records into a mysql/mariadb.  Then a web based interface can be designed, and viewed on any web browser on any device that has access to his network.  (VPN externally).  The reason I ask is because it would easy to write a program with such simple requirements.  SQL  select * from music_table where name is like %user inputed value%;  This could be hidden with PHP directly or a framework like laravel.

Answer (score 0):

The one that I have come across in the past is [Collectorz](https://www.collectorz.com/music). It has various versions: web, desktop, mobile. But it has a yearly charge...
You can download a trial version, to check it out. It has the ability to scan for CD details physically or via its online database, or by barcode, etc. So you don't have to enter all details.

Another solution to this is to use an online music database like [MusicBrainz](https://musicbrainz.org/) or [Discogs](https://discogs.com/) and maintain a personal collection there. There are data importers if you search their forums. There are also mobile apps available.

Edit:
Another one I stumbled on recently is [Rayons](https://github.com/gdiggs/rayons)